# Comparing derivatives of two decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have two differantiable functions $f$ and $g$ on $x \in[0,\infty)$ such that

1. $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$,
2. $f'(x)<0$ and $g'(x)<0$,
3. $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(x)>g(x)$

Observe all inequalities are strict.

**Is it true that $f'(x) \ge g'(x)$ for all $x \in[0,\infty)$?**

Intuitivly what about says is that if $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are two deacresing functions that start at a same point and $f(x)$ is alwasy bigger than $g(x)$ then $g(x)$ should decrease faster than $f(x)$.

The question is how to show this?

An exmaple of such functions would be $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

Comment: what if $g$ decreases really fast at first then slows down enough?

Comment: @hHhh but then $f(x)$ eventually overtake $g(x)$ and would be smaller? Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another counterexample is $f(x)= 1/(1+x),g(x) = 1/(1+x)^2.$

In fact, take any positive $f$ with $f(0) = 1, f'< 0,$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0.$ Then $g(x)= f(x)^2$ provides a counterexample. Proof: We have $0< f < 1$ on $(0,\infty),$ which implies $g<f$ there. Because $g'(x) = 2f(x)f'(x)$ and $f\to 0,$ we have $g'(x) > f'(x)$ for large $x.$

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider $$f(x)=e^\frac{-x}{200}\times\cases{ e^{\frac{-1}{(x-5)^2}+\frac{1}{25}}+1&\text{ if }x\leq5\\
1 & \text{ if } x>5}$$
$$g(x)=2e^{-x}.$$
The following plot demonstrates the issue:
[image]

The $f$ function is smooth, and decays much more slowly than $g$.

The derivatives are:
$$f'(x)=e^\frac{-x}{200}\times\cases{\frac{-1}{200}e^{\frac{-1}{(x-5)^2}+\frac{1}{25}}+1+\frac{2}{(x-5)^3}e^{\frac{-1}{(x-5)^2}+\frac{1}{25}}&\text{ if }x\leq5\\
\frac{-1}{200} & \text{ if } x>5}$$
$$g'(x)=-2e^{-x}.$$

Comment: could you show the derivatives?

Comment: actually never mind. Did it myself. Thanks for the example

Comment: Do you think I can change the stament  to: there exists some $x_0$  such that for all $x \in [x_0, \infty)$  $g'(x) \le f'(x)$.

Comment: I apologize, but in my previous example, $f(10)=g(10)$ and $f(x)<g(x)$ for $x\geq 10$. This example is more pathological, but it works.

Comment: @Boby That is definitely true because it must be true at 0.

Comment: In your new example is $f(x)$ differantiable at $x=5$??

Comment: Yes it is. the base function $$f(x)=\cases{e^{-1/x^2} & \text{ if } x\geq 0\\ 0 & \text{ if } x<0}$$ is a standard counterexample to the false notion that smooth functions cannot be zero over an interval.